# Uncaught handler NullPointerException on a custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

This is where I set my custom ArrayAdapter:

```
lv.setAdapter(new MatchArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, g.dm.getMatchesOnTeam(teamId), getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(),getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()));
```

This is my MatchArrayAdapter:

```
public class MatchArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Match> {
private Match[] matches;
private int height;
private int width;
private Context context;

public MatchArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        Match[] objects, int width, int height) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.matches = objects;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.matchlistview, null);
    }
    //Get all the views
    TextView opponent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MatchOpponent);
    TextView month = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MatchMonth);
    TextView day = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MatchDay);
    ImageView matchMoreInformation = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MatchMoreInformation);

    opponent.setText("vs. "+matches[position].getOpponentTeam().getTeamName());
    LayoutParams lpo = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpo.setMargins((int)(width*0.15), (int)(height*0.04), 0, 0);
    opponent.setLayoutParams(lpo);

    month.setText(String.valueOf(matches[position].getDate().get(Calendar.MONTH)));
    LayoutParams lpm = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpm.setMargins((int)(width*0.02), 0, 0, 0);
    month.setLayoutParams(lpm);

    day.setText(String.valueOf(matches[position].getDate().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
    LayoutParams lpd = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpd.setMargins((int)(width*0.07), (int)(height*0.05), 0, 0);
    day.setLayoutParams(lpd);

    //"Next" arrow, arrow for more information of the match
    matchMoreInformation.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
    LayoutParams lpmmi = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpmmi.setMargins((int)(width*0.81), (int)(height*0.044), 0, 0); 
    matchMoreInformation.setLayoutParams(lpmmi);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

And I'm always getting the following errors:

```
07-26 13:47:24.034: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at data.MatchArrayAdapter.getView(MatchArrayAdapter.java:41)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1668)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:694)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1521)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:996)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-26 13:47:24.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've been trying all I've found. But nothing fix it out.

Edit:
The code of line 41 is:

```
opponent.setText("vs. "+matches[position].getOpponentTeam().getTeamName());
```

I've set a breakpoint in that line and, `matches[position].getOpponentTeam().getTeamName()` is not null.

2nd edit:
This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MatchOpponent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MatchMonth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MatchDay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/MatchMoreInformation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The exception suggests that something is null in your getView method at the line number 41. Can you post the code on the line 41? Most probably some of the textviews is not found in the convertView. You are calling your Adapter with the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` layout, you probably want to replace this with your custom layout.

Comment: What is in the line number 41 of MatchArrayAdapter.java ?

Comment: opponent.setText("vs. "+matches[position].getOpponentTeam().getTeamName());

Answer (score 1):

There is only one error there(the rest is stacktrace)and it is on line 41 of your source inside `getView` method(I think the code you posted does not include import statements etc. so I cannot know exactly which line it is).

You are trying to use a null object.

**EDIT:**
If `matches[position].getOpponentTeam().getTeamName()` is not `null` then are you sure that `opponent` is not null? And are you sure `R.id.MatchOpponent` is a `TextView`

Comment: @Alex And are you sure `R.id.MatchOpponent` is a `TextView`? Maybe you are doing a wrong cast...

Comment: If I had done a wrong casting the exception will be ClassCastException. I'm not doing a wrong cast.

Answer (score 1):

Are  you sure that 'MatchOpponent' control was defined in matchlistview layout and was not defined in any other layout? Maybe this control was not inflated successful.